# Как работает PRIMARY KEY в sqlite

Tags: sqlite3

После удаления строки получается разрыв в последовательности ID в таблицы. Так и должно быть?
После добавления новой записи в таблицу, ей был присвоен id = 102, предыдущий id = 47. Как это работает?

Comment: Как я понял, немного поэкспериментировать, если id уже был использован, но потом освобожден, то sqlite больше его не присваивает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так и должно быть. Всё суть идентификаторов в их неизменности. И это не только в SQLite, а вообще во всех СУБД. Работает это за счёт того, что SQLite для каждой таблицы хранит непрерывно нарастающий счётчик выданных идентификаторов.

Если в БД есть хоть одна таблица с autoincrement-полем

```
create table some_table (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  some_field text
);

insert into some_table (some_field) value ('one value'), ('another value');
```

то увидеть счётчик идентификаторов можно так

```
select * from sqlite_sequence where name = 'some_table';
```

Вывод

```
name        seq
----------  ----------
some_table  2
```